# Most compressed way to store String Object

Tags: java, string, object, binary, save

I have A String object that I want to save to a file, and I dont care if it is saved as plain text or binary. I have tried saving as plain text and it was about 27 bytes. I then tried `ObjectOutputStream` and it was 24 bytes. Is there any better way of saving String objects to a file? The string is 189:25:600:-324324214& and intend to have thousands of them. Thats why I want it compressed, and of course each String will be a bit different

Comment: it may depend on the String.

Comment: You're worried about compressing a 24-byte file?

Comment: The string is 189:25:600:-324324214& and intend to have thousands of them. Thats why I want it compressed, of course they will be different.

Comment: It sounds like you might need to use a database.

Comment: I was considering SQlite

Comment: Do you need to read individual strings from the file, or are you going to read the "thousands of them" all at once? This imposes different compression requirements.

Comment: I want to store them in one file, pretty much they are going to be in an array and I am going to loop the array and write them to a file. And I will read them all at once.

Comment: And by thousands I mean about 10,000,000 Strings like that in one file

Comment: You're going to read and write an array of 10 million strings with a total length of 0.27 GiB? I don't know what you're doing this for, but you might want to reconsider your design.

Comment: That is How I want it because I am storing a lot of data. The input file can range from 10MB to 4GB.

Comment: This smells of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Better for you to describe in greater detail just what you're trying to do, not how you're trying to solve it with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap a `FileOutputStream` inside a `DeflatorOutputStream` inside an `ObjectOutputStream` to create the file. (Write the entire array as a single object.) Then wrap a `FileInputStream` inside an `InflatorInputStream` inside an `ObjectInputStream` to read.

Comment: So `DeflatorStream>FileOutputStream>ObjectOutputStream`? Two streams in one?

Comment: Actually, three streams in one: `OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(aFile); Deflator deflator = new Deflator(Deflator.BEST_COMPRESSION); OutputStream dos = new DeflatorOutputStream(fos, deflator); OutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(dos)`.

Comment: This doesn't work for small objects but it is good for larger objects which is what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Followings are some option to use for compressing:

1. [GZIPOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html) ("deflate in gzip wrapper")
2. [DeflaterOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.html) ("plain deflate", recommend over gzip or
   zip "wrappers") standard
3. [LZMA Java implementations](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html)
4. [jZlib](http://www.jcraft.com/jzlib/)
5. [LZO-Java](https://github.com/Karmasphere/lzo-java)
6. [Lz4-java and LZ4-HC](https://github.com/jpountz/lz4-java) (Lz4 fast with reasonable compression ratio, LZ4-HC is for high compression)
7. [XZ](http://tukaani.org/xz/java.html) (incorporates the LZMA2 compression algorithm)
8. [snappy-java](http://code.google.com/p/snappy-java/) (used JNI,  developed by Google based on ideas from LZ77)

Well i have only used 1,2,4 and 7 until now :). using XZ seems reasonable to me, fast and higher compression ration and very easy to use.

```
XZOutputStream out = new XZOutputStream(outstream, LZMA2Options);
InputStream in = new XZInputStream(anInputstream);
```

Comment: One thing is that after I am done saving it, it will be in an archive with three other files so dearchiving twice would make it pretty slow. I am using LZMA compression to do it.

Comment: The problem with `GZIPOutputStream` is that you have to subclass it to get any compression.

Comment: @user2317720 you can wrap `FileOutputStream` inside a `DeflatorOutputStream` before writing the file.

Comment: @Tedd Hopp, yes you are right. GZIP stream extends the Deflate implementation with additional details specific to the GZIP file format.